# How to find parameter k of negative binomial distribution using size and mu data in R?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, negative-binomial-distribution

I fit a negative binomial distribution and I have size = 0.47 and mu = 134. 85 for population 1, and size = 0.26 and mu = 136.49 in population 2. How do I find the parameter k, to infer which of the populations had more over-dispersion? Ideally, greater the value of k, the larger the dispersion.